# Speed up JSONB full text search in PostgreSQL/SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, jsonb

The performance of my JSONB full text search is awfully slow using PostgreSQL and SQLAlchemy. How can I speed it up?

### Model

```
class Book(Base):
    __tablename__ = "book"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    jsondata = Column(JSONB)
    __table_args__ = (Index('index_jsondesc',
                      text("(jsondata->'description') jsonb_path_ops"),
                      postgresql_using="gin"),)
```

### Full text search in the JSONB column

```
class BookSearch:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def search(keyword):
        self.query = self.query.filter(Book.jsondata['description'].cast(Unicode).match(keyword))

booksearch = BookSearch()
booksearch.search("Python")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given selective enough queries, speeding up full text search queries means having the proper index in place. `jsonb_path_ops` do not benefit full text search:

> The non-default GIN operator class `jsonb_path_ops` supports indexing the `@>` operator only.

Instead you need (for example) a [functional index for explicit `to_tsvector()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-tables.html#TEXTSEARCH-TABLES-INDEX):

```
class Book(Base):
    __tablename__ = "book"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    jsondata = Column(JSONB)
    __table_args__ = (
        Index('index_jsondesc',
              func.to_tsvector('english', jsondata['description'].astext),
              postgresql_using="gin"),
    )
```

Note that you must choose the configuration to use when defining the index. Your query must then match the configuration used in the index:

```
def search(keyword):
    tsvector = func.to_tsvector('english', Book.jsondata['description'].astext)
    self.query = self.query.filter(tsvector.match(keyword))
```